# MySQL procedure syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax, procedure

Does anyone of you know how to use a VARCHAR parameter inside a MySQL procedure?
I tried the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure_name` (IN name VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONCAT(name) (`id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `uid` VARCHAR(32));
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `name` (`id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `uid` VARCHAR(32));
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name (`id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `uid` VARCHAR(32));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

with

```
CALL procedure_name('test');
```

but it always creates a table called "name" instead of "test".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `CONCAT` with `statement` to construct the query and execute it, e.g.:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure_name` (IN name VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN 

    SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS', name, '(`id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `uid` VARCHAR(32))');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query ;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: +1 This is working perfectly. But how do I call it? Trying "CALL procedure_name('helloWorld')" throws an syntax error near ')'.

Comment: @mickedplay added `CREATE` syntax, try now?

Comment: Found my mistake. I had an error in my CREATE TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

`Name` appears to be a reserve keyword. Also IN is default type for parameters.  Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure_name` ( p_name VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS p_name (`id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `uid` VARCHAR(32));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```